# Is there an official way to switch tabs within Slack from a button click?

Tags: slack, slack-api

**Note**: I'm using the `slack-java-sdk` but I'm assuming this problem/solution can be quite SDK agnostic.

**Use case:**

So, an action I'd like to perform is when a user clicks on a button in a bot's app homepage I'd like to switch directly to the messages tab on click.

**Current solution:**

Right now I've found a hack with something like:

```
button {
     text("Button title :wave:")
     actionId(ButtonEventId.GENERIC_BUTTON_EVENT_ID.id)
     url("slack://app?team=${ctx.teamId}&id=${environmentVarsProvider.slackAppId()}&tab=messages")
}
```

So, when they click not only is a `block_action` payload to `app.blockAction(ButtonEventId.GENERIC_BUTTON_EVENT_ID.id)` sent via the events endpoint, but it'll also trigger the `url()` and navigate the user to the messages tab on desktop.

**The problem**:
The problem I'm having is that on some mobile devices, it'll open the browser with a dead link. I'm curious whether there is a more official way of switching tabs within the Slack client without the issue of dead links.

[image: image showing dead link in browser]